# Odd behavior in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a table like so

```
<table>
  <tr id="trRow1" runat="server" style="display: none">
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><asp:Label id="lblFirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><asp:Label id="lblLastName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, initially the first row is not being displayed. When the user clicks a certain radio button on the page an asynchronous postback occurs, and at that time I set the style of trRow1 to "inline". Nothing fancy; nothing new. It works just great.

Or at least up until I try to do the following in a javascript function.

```
function Test() {       
  var obj = trRow1.getElementsByTagName("select");
  alert(obj.length);
}
```

At the point I call Test(), I get an error that says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'trRow1' is undefined."

My guess is it has something to do with the fact that I'm messing with setting the Display style using AJAX, and for whatever reason the DOM can't find trRow1 even after I set it's display to "inline".

Can anyone throw me a bone on this one? I'm stuck.

Comment: Oops, thank you for catching that mistake. It was supposed to say trRow1. I edited my original code a little bit, hoping that it would make my question easier to understand.

Comment: Is this the actual code that is causing the error, or just an example that is like the code? Unless I misunderstood your question, you have posted an example that is similar to the buggy code, but given the error message from the actual code. This will make it very hard for anyone to find subtle errors in your code. Please either post the original, or reproduce the error in your sample code and give us the sample error instead of the production error.

Comment: Don't make a mountain out of a molehill, please. I edited the problem areas of my question, and it is sufficient as it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object *trDegree* is not defined, by your naming conventions looks like *trDegree i*s a table row element, I think that you're trying to do something like this:

```
function WTF() {       
  var trDegree = document.getElementById('trDegree'); // Locate the element
  var obj = trDegree.getElementsByTagName("select");
  alert(obj.length);
}
```

Further Reference:

- [element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. My example code should have read trRow1, and not trDegree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any variable for trDegree in your sample.  You would need to have trDegree loaded before calling getElementsByTagName.

For example:

```
function WTF() {
  var trDegree = document.getElementById('trDegree'); 
  var obj = trDegree.getElementsByTagName("select");
  alert(obj.length);
}
```

or you could just load the tags from the document level.  I'm not sure if this is the effect you want though.

```
function WTF() {
  var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  alert(obj.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the first answer. U must get the element before using it adding this line:

```
var trRow1 = document.getElementById('trRow1');
```